# Laravel custom directives cause HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Doesn't happen on local web server, only on host, PHP 7.1.  Get nothing but a blank 500 error page, no clues, nothing in the logs.

I have a couple custom Blade directives that I use to generate just the HTML for a download button and a last modified date inside a , for a downloads page listing numerous downloads.

Directives in AppServiceProvider.php:

```
    Blade::directive('fileDate', function ($file) {
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            $timestamp = filemtime(str_replace(["'", '"'], "", $file));
            return view('components.file-date', ['timestamp' => $timestamp]);
        }

        return '-';
    });

    Blade::directive('downloadButton', function($file) {
        return view('components.download-button', ['link' => asset(trim($file, "'"))]);
    });
```

The views it's referencing:

file-date.blade.php:

```
<span class="filedate">{{ date('d/m/Y H:i', $timestamp) }}</span>
```

download-button.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ $link }}" class="button secondary">Download</a>
```

Used like so inside the template:

```
<td>                         
   @fileDate('media/file1.zip')
   @downloadButton('media/file1.zip')
</td>
```

---

It works fine on another page for a separate set of downloads, but something is causing it to fall over on the main downloads page, and I can't get any sort of information from the error page at all.

I've tried commenting sections out but it just doesn't want to work on this particular page.

Any advice?  Perhaps some way of getting some more information about the error?  Debug mode is fully enabled as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

1. Check web server log. You can find the log path in the configuration file in field 'error_log'.
2. Also, you can check php-fpm log if you use it.
3. And, the laravel framework log. Defult in `storage/logs`
4. At last, you can use `try catch`, try the 'problem code' and catch it, then print it or log to file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try turning on debug mode on in your .env file to see if you can get any useful error messages

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Comment: Alternatively I've found that if you are using too many views turning debug mode off will help the page load.